# wildcard search (?, *) in a string array using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to achieve wild card search on a string array using java script 
Here the wild cards i use are  ? -to represent single char  and * to represent multiple char

here is my string array

```
var sample = new Array();
sample[0] = 'abstract';
sample[1] = 'cabinet';
sample[2] = 'computer';
```

For example i searched for a string 'ab*t' in the array and the regular expression I used for this is '\ab.*t\', but the problem is I get both  'abstract' and 'cabinet' as matching strings. I only want the string that starts with 'ab' and not where it comes in the middle.

So I modified my regexp like this '\^ab.*t$\ but still the same result. So can somebody give me some tips on how this can be achieved.

Comment: ``\^ab.*t$\`` is bizarre. Did you mean to write `/^ab.*t$/`? (It might help if you posted the actual code . . .)

Answer (score 1):

You are using using wrong wrong slashs you should use forward slash('/') instead of backward slashs ('\') 
probably it'll help you `/^ab.*t$/`